# Whats the best practice to validate plugin with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need write a jQuery plugin to validate forms, I was thinking on something like this to start:

Just a EXAMPLE:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var isValid = true;
    var required = $('.required').val();

    if(required== ''){
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
});
```

I'ts a good practice? exist some pattern to validate forms?, What is the best option?

Note: I wont use a plugin.
    ​

Comment: `$('.required').val()` will only give you the value of the first required `input`. That's *not* what you want.

Comment: By your note at the end, I take it you're aware that there are already jquery form validation plugins available, but you're wanting to write your own. Is that correct?

Comment: Its correct, but I want write a plugin to apply it on my work.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('.required').each(function(){
         if($(this).val() == ''){
            isValid = false;
         }
    })
    return isValid;
});
```

Comment: This'll indicate validity even if only the last element is filled in. You have to return false from within the looping function, so that it stops the loop once an error has been found.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

```
$('form').submit(function()
{
    var isValid = true;

    $('.required', this).each(function()
    {
        if (this.value == '')
        {
            isValid = false;

            $(this).addClass('error').focus();

            return false;
        }
    });

    return isValid;
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DUNc2/

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to use a plugin but it's a great way to learn, you can download the most popular jquery validation plugin here:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Take some lessons from how that plugin is made to create your own.

Comment: Because I want make my own plugin is for that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that?  I understand you want to make your own plugin.  My suggestion is to learn from others to do that.